# inside a script module, try to import js files with twig asset() (error: myalias.x is not a function)

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, webpack, twig

[ Environment: symfony (PHP), twig files with HTML/JS code, and Managing assets with Webpack ]

**Files Tree**

```
_assets
 |__js
    |__file.js
    |__library
       |__ps
          |__index.js
_public
 |__build
    |__js
       |__myfile.js (auto generated by webpack)

_src
_templates
 |__mypage
    |__page.html.twig

_webpack.config.js
```

Normally in a **file.js** you perform an import, and then use/call the exported functions/variables using the alias given:

**library/ps/index.js**

```
export function x(){
   console.log('hi !');
}
```

**file.js**

```
import * as myalias from "../../../assets/js/library/ps";

myalias.x();
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
...

.addEntry('js/myfile', './assets/js/file.js')

...
```

**page.html.twig**

```
...

{% block javascript %}
   {{ encore_entry_script_tags('js/myfile') }}
{% endblock %}

...
```

**web console (google chrome)**

```
hi !
```

(EVERYTHING UTIL HERE WORKS PERFECTLY)

---

**Files Tree**

```
_assets
 |__js
    |__library
       |__ps
          |__index.js
_public
 |__build
    |__js
       |__mylibrary.js (auto generated by webpack)

_src
_templates
 |__mypage
    |__page.html.twig
    |__page_JS.html.twig

_webpack.config.js
```

My Goal is to do the same thing, but having the JS code in a twig file. Because I gain more advantages passing, in some cases, the twig variables to the js code.

The problem is that I get an error, in the web console. `Uncaught TypeError: myalias.x is not a function`

**library/ps/index.js**

```
export function x(){
   console.log('hi !');
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
...

.addEntry('js/mylibrary', './assets/js/library/ps/index.js')

...
```

**page_JS.html.twig**

```
<script type="module">

    import * as myalias from "{{ asset('build/js/mylibrary.js') }}";

    myalias.x();

</script>
```

the code is inside the `<scrip type="module">`, because with it, we can use the import/export functionalities that normally inside a normal `<script>` we don't have. **(if I understood right)**
PS. the path is `build` because the webpack generate the file in the public folder.

**page.html.twig**

```
...

{% block javascript %}
   {% include 'mypage/_page_JS.html.twig' %}
{% endblock %}

...
```

**web console (google chrome)**

```
Uncaught TypeError: myalias.x is not a function
```

Comment: Doesn't `asset(...)` generate an absolute path whilst import relies on relative paths?

Comment: Is `build/js/mylibrary.js` the actual path that would be accessible from the webserver by a browser? In other words, would that JS file actually be at `yourwebsite.com/build/js/mylibrary.js` or instead `yourwebsite.com/js/mylibrary.js`? Also, where is your `index.php` located in that project tree?

Comment: Yes, Webpack will generate it (yourwebsite.com/build/js/mylibrary.js) in the public folder under build. And also the index.php is located in the public folder. Basically, everything that you want accessible is added in the public folder manually by you or automatically by the webpack.

Comment: Are you transpiling to commonjs with babel? If so then you are mixing module types and your `x` might be attached to the `.default` property of the imported namespace `myalias`. Try `myalias.default.x()` or console.log `myalias` to see what properties are present.

Comment: Similar to what @morganney said, could you show us `public/build/js/mylibrary.js` and the full contents of your `webpack.config.js`? I think this is likely an issue with the webpack configuration

Comment: What does `"{{ asset('build/js/mylibrary.js') }}"` output when you inspect the rendered template in your browser dev tools?

Comment: @OluwafemiSule in the browser I get this with the asset ->   import * as myalias from "/build/js/myLibrary.js";      and if I search in the source section I can find that webpack generated file called myLibrary.js I also tried to console.log myalias as (morganney) suggest here the result Module {Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): 'Module'} an the object is empty